# Grape: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, grape-api

When calling my API Endpoint, I am getting this error:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

**day_points_api.rb**

```
module V1
  class DayPointsApi < Grape::API
    namespace 'api/v1' do
      resource :points do
        desc 'start all metrik jobs'

        params do
          requires :product, type: String
          requires :type, type: String
          requires :value_at, type: Date

          requires :points, type: Array do
            requires :platform, type: String
            requires :country, type: String
            requires :value, type: Float
          end
        end

        post do
          params[:points].each do |point|
            point_params = point.merge(params.except(:points))
            DayPoint.constantize.import(point_params)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Clearly, this is due to StrongParameter - but to be honest, I already define what parameters are required - these should be the only ones allowed by default.

There are some solutions available [using helper methods](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/issues/404) - which I find are ugly.

How is this possible? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching the internet everywhere else, I found the solution in the [official Grape Docs](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#rails) - what a champ! /sarcasm

> If the version of your Rails is 4.0+ and the application uses the
>   default model layer of ActiveRecord, you will want to use the
>   [hashie-forbidden_attributes gem](https://github.com/Maxim-Filimonov/hashie-forbidden_attributes). This gem disables the security
>   feature of strong_params at the model layer, allowing you the use of
>   Grape's own params validation instead.

I added this to SO to help anyone who should stumble like me.